# How to record stub-code for mocked objects

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mocking, tdd

Im using NSubstitute for creating mocked objects, basically I am mocking the DAL methods that is used in each unittest (response objects).

I have some great testscenarios in the database that I would like to reproduce as mocked representations (since the data might change).

Is there any way (framework? add-in?) to record/generate code for creating stubbed representations of these calls to the database, to be used in unit tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Object Exporter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6a21c68-f815-4895-999f-cd0885d8774f) in the past for this exact scenario. It will serialize an in memory object (debug time) to CSharp code for use in a stub library.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6a21c68-f815-4895-999f-cd0885d8774f

Obviously, only applies if you are using Visual Studio.

Good luck!